# Replace backwards formatting of string of numbers in R

Tags: r, string

I have  a dataset which consists of a bunch of codes. For the most part, the data is entered in this format.

```
a <- XX-XXXX
b <- 12-4567
```

The X is any number between 0 to 9. It should be noted that the number of digits AFTER the dash can vary. For the purposes of this example, there are four numbers the dash, but the data can contain 1 number or 9 numbers after the dash.

However, some data has been entered as this format:

```
c <- XXXX-XX
d <- 4567-12
```

What I would like to do is to flip it so that whatever comes after the dash is put back into the beginning and the rest of the number is separated by a dash (-). The actual order of the digits does not need to change.

I've tried str_replace_all, but that just seems to remove the whole string after the dash.

Any thoughts on how to resolve this issue is greatly appreciated. I'm using R.

Comment: `gsub("([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)", "\\2-\\1", "12-4567")`

Comment: You can try `gsub("(\\w+)-(\\w+)", "\\2-\\1", c("XX-XXXX", "12-4567"))`

Comment: @r2evans Thank you for the solution. I quickly copied the formula and it worked. If I'm interpreting this correctly, I assume this part captures the formatting of my data. But what does "\\2-\\1" mean?

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding - thank you for your solution for as well. I'm not very well very versed in R, can you explain what this segment "(\\w+)-(\\w+)" means? Thank you!

Comment: @akrun Unfortunately, in my data, there are situations where there are more than 4 digits so your solution, while it works seems to be too specific. Sorry if I wasn't clear on that parameter in my original post.

Comment: @user13893942 `\\w+` matches multiple word characters

Comment: The `\\1` and `\\2` are back-references to the `(...)` grouping in the first pattern. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3358272 for good notes about regular expressions.